# How to fix this script to color words that appear repeated in a text area?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a script to find and coloring values that appear repeated in my text area, I am using as separator the following symbols: "|", " ", "~", I tried constructing an array with the frequencies of the words in the text, then I just build a list of word that appear repeated in the text called: colorWords it looks like this:

```
var colorWords = Object.keys(filtered)
```

Then I tried to color that words by creating a method to find them and replace them for a string with ans specific color:

```
'<span style="color:'+colors[Math.floor((Math.random(148) * colors.length) + 1)]+'">'+colorWords[i]+'</span>'
```

I am using a random generator to assign the color, but I failed coloring the repeated words since my script is coloring all the matches of the characters that contain a word of my list called colorWords, It is coloring all the "X", and all the substrings that matchs, I would like to fix it and improve my code, my complete code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"><script src="./code33_files/lodash.js"></script> 
</head><body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<textarea cols="150" rows="15" id="texto">
"RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX4.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X3|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGX6.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX8.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXA.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
</textarea>
<div id="out1"></div>
<script>
var text = document.getElementById("texto").value;
var splitWords = text.split(/[["\|~]/);
var cleanArray  = _.remove(splitWords, function (word) {return word !== '' && word !== ' ' && word !== '\n'});
var dict = cleanArray.reduce(function(p,c) {
    if (p[c] === undefined) {
        p[c] = 1;
    } else {
        p[c]++;
    }
    return p;
},{});
console.log(dict);
var filtered = Object.keys(dict).reduce(function (filtered, key) {
    if (dict[key] > 1) filtered[key] = dict[key];
    return filtered;
}, {});
var colorWords = Object.keys(filtered)
colors = ["AliceBlue","AntiqueWhite","Aqua","Aquamarine","Azure","Beige","Bisque","Black","BlanchedAlmond","Blue","BlueViolet","Brown","BurlyWood","CadetBlue","Chartreuse","Chocolate","Coral","CornflowerBlue","Cornsilk","Crimson","Cyan","DarkBlue","DarkCyan","DarkGoldenRod","DarkGray","DarkGrey","DarkGreen","DarkKhaki","DarkMagenta","DarkOliveGreen","DarkOrange","DarkOrchid","DarkRed","DarkSalmon","DarkSeaGreen","DarkSlateBlue","DarkSlateGray","DarkSlateGrey","DarkTurquoise","DarkViolet","DeepPink","DeepSkyBlue","DimGray","DimGrey","DodgerBlue","FireBrick","FloralWhite","ForestGreen","Fuchsia","Gainsboro","GhostWhite","Gold","GoldenRod","Gray","Grey","Green","GreenYellow","HoneyDew","HotPink","IndianRed","Indigo","Ivory","Khaki","Lavender","LavenderBlush","LawnGreen","LemonChiffon","LightBlue","LightCoral","LightCyan","LightGoldenRodYellow","LightGray","LightGrey","LightGreen","LightPink","LightSalmon","LightSeaGreen","LightSkyBlue","LightSlateGray","LightSlateGrey","LightSteelBlue","LightYellow","Lime","LimeGreen","Linen","Magenta","Maroon","MediumAquaMarine","MediumBlue","MediumOrchid","MediumPurple","MediumSeaGreen","MediumSlateBlue","MediumSpringGreen","MediumTurquoise","MediumVioletRed","MidnightBlue","MintCream","MistyRose","Moccasin","NavajoWhite","Navy","OldLace","Olive","OliveDrab","Orange","OrangeRed","Orchid","PaleGoldenRod","PaleGreen","PaleTurquoise","PaleVioletRed","PapayaWhip","PeachPuff","Peru","Pink","Plum","PowderBlue","Purple","RebeccaPurple","Red","RosyBrown","RoyalBlue","SaddleBrown","Salmon","SandyBrown","SeaGreen","SeaShell","Sienna","Silver","SkyBlue","SlateBlue","SlateGray","SlateGrey","Snow","SpringGreen","SteelBlue","Tan","Teal","Thistle","Tomato","Turquoise","Violet","Wheat","White","WhiteSmoke","Yellow","YellowGreen"]
for (i = 0; i < colorWords.length; i++) { 
    word=colorWords[i];
    text = text.replace(new RegExp(word, 'g'), '<span style="color:'+colors[Math.floor((Math.random(148) * colors.length) + 1)]+'">'+colorWords[i]+'</span>');
}
document.getElementById("out1").innerHTML = text;
</script>
</body></html>
```

I order to not consider this question as douplicated I would like to say that this time I am searching to fix the method that makes the replacement, which is presented below:

```
for (i = 0; i < colorWords.length; i++) { 
    word=colorWords[i];
    text = text.replace(new RegExp(word, 'g'), '<span style="color:'+colors[Math.floor((Math.random(148) * colors.length) + 1)]+'">'+colorWords[i]+'</span>');
}
```

And also ways to improve my code since this was the approach that I used at first to solve the problem, and to color that strings, I also loose the separation between lines when I display the textarea coloreated, I would like to fix it, I appreciate suggestions of how to achieve this.

Comment: For starters, [`Math.random` doesn't take an argument.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) It always returns a number from [0, 1).

Comment: this method is actually giving me a random integer from 1 to 148 which is the length  of my list of colors.

Comment: It's doing that because you're multiplying it by `colors.length`. I'm just saying, there's no reason to pass an argument to `Math.random`. It doesn't use it.

Comment: Ok I already understand your point, I will consider it.

Comment: Did you try out a regexp string like "\\b"+word+"\\b". "\\b" or /\b/ at the beginning/ending of word will try to find a non-word character. So RDB won't match RDB3.

Comment: No I have not, but I already tried with your regexp and I finally got the desired result, I really appreciate the support, maybe you could post the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/tfhg9ccd/
With the regexp modification (using "\b"):

```
new RegExp("\\b"+word+"\\b", 'g')
```

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful.

Comment: just one quickly question, this is printing one long line, Do you know how to print it line per line?

Comment: See the css view in the jsfiddle.

Comment: yes in that case is printing it line per line, but when I open the code in chrome just print one long line, I would like to present it line per line.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "open the code in chrome".

Comment: I mean copy the complete code and save it in a file called for instance my code.html to then open it with a browser like Google chrome of Internet Explorer.

Comment: if you copy the  <div id="out1"> entirely and the css, it should work like in the example.

Comment: I understand, should I save the css in a separate file? or I just can I copy the code inside the <div id="out1">  code,

Comment: you can put it inside the <div> style attribute, inside a <style> or inside a file, yes.

Comment: Ok I understand, I really appreciate your support, I will try to achieve that, I prefer to put it inside the <div>.